# How to create a document with a subcollection within Firestore cloud function?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

Hi I'd like to create the following document with the `private` subcollection, via a cloud function trigger:

[image]

This is what I have so far, but have no idea how to actually set a subcollection as well.

```js
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {value: true});

// Cloud Functions for Firebase SDK to create Cloud Functions + set up triggers.
const functions = require("firebase-functions");

// The Firebase Admin SDK to access Firestore.
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

// Listen to .onCreate trigger
exports.createProfile = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
  return admin.firestore().doc(`/users/${user.uid}`).set({
    firstName: null,
    lastName: null,
    preferredName: null,
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

A reference to a doc can be formed by alternating `collection` and `doc` references.  Going a little overboard to spell it out...

```
const usersCollectionRef = firestore().collection('users')
const userRef = usersCollectionRef.doc(user.uid);
const privatesCollectionRef = userRef.collection('private');
const accountRef = privatesCollectionRef.doc('account');

return accountRef.set(...)

// or, the other extreme lines-of-code-wise
const accountRef = firestore().doc(`/users/${user.uid}/private/account`)
return accountRef.set(...)
```

Note that you'll only be able to have one doc at a time named "account" in the "private" collection. Not sure about the semantics of your app, but the user's email inside that doc might be a better doc name.